# Opening the new window and closing the old window in chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am opening the child window with window.open() to Download and view the document. After downloading the document i want to close current window and open a new window. The below code is working fine in IE11 but not working in chrome.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", "<script>window.open('DocumentsView.aspx?FileName=" + Server.UrlEncode(Filename) + "');setTimeout(window.close, 10);</script>");
```

in chrome new window also closing automatically but in IE it's opening a new window.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.open` has a handle and a window name.

Use

```
var myWindow = window.open("Document.....","_blank"); 
setTimeout(function() { myWindow.close() },100);
```

Comment: I don't have handle. I am opening this window from another window. now i want to close this window and open a new window from it.

Comment: You have a handle if you define one